# Can I write an interface for a template class in C++

Tags: c++, g++, polymorphism

I have an interface and a couple of implementations of a class that stores serialized objects.  I'd like to make the implementation classes into template classes so I can use them with more than one type of object, but I'm getting compiler errors.

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class Interface{
public:
    virtual void func(T& c) = 0;
};

class Container{
public:
    Container() : dummy(10){}
    int dummy;
};


template<typename T>
class Implementation : public Interface{
public:
    void func(T& c){
        std::cout << "++c.dummy " << ++c.dummy << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Container c;
    Implementation<Container> i;
    i.func(c);
    return 0;
}
```

I get "error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token" at the "class Implementation..." line.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because comments like that are not welcome in this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
class Implementation : public Interface<T> {
//                                     ^^^
```

Comment: Your `^^^` is a tad misaligned.  I think.

Comment: @strager: Looks fine here with Consolas. It should be directly below the `<T>`.

Comment: @Strager: as long as the ^^^ points at the <T> after Interface, it is correctly aligned.

Comment: Ah; I have Opera scaled at 150%, which for some reason cause misalignments.  At 100% it's fine.  Weird...